# How To Bind the JSON Sub Array Data into Listview in xamarin.forms

Tags: listview, binding, xamarin.forms

I want to bind the data coming from JSON to ListView in xamarin.forms. i have made the call and i have parsed the data from JSON. Now i am not able to understand the best way to bind the data in the xamarin.forms that is.

JSON:

```
[{"Product":"XXX","Origins":[{"Origin":"ORI1","Details":[{"Seller":"Name","Seller_Rate":"256","Saller_QTY":"20","Buyer":"Name","Buyer_Rate":"256","Buyer_QTY":"20"},{"Seller":"Name","Seller_Rate":"256","Saller_QTY":"20","Buyer":"Name","Buyer_Rate":"256","Buyer_QTY":"20"}]},{"Origin":"ORI2","Details":[{"Seller":"Name","Seller_Rate":"256","Saller_QTY":"20","Buyer":"Name","Buyer_Rate":"256","Buyer_QTY":"20"},{"Seller":"Name","Seller_Rate":"256","Saller_QTY":"20","Buyer":"Name","Buyer_Rate":"256","Buyer_QTY":"20"}]}]},{"Product":"PQR","Origins":[{"Origin":"ABC","Details":[{"Seller":"Name","Seller_Rate":"256","Saller_QTY":"20","Buyer":"Name","Buyer_Rate":"256","Buyer_QTY":"20"},{"Seller":"Name","Seller_Rate":"256","Saller_QTY":"20","Buyer":"Name","Buyer_Rate":"256","Buyer_QTY":"20"}]},{"Origin":"PPP","Details":[{"Seller":"Name","Seller_Rate":"256","Saller_QTY":"20","Buyer":"Name","Buyer_Rate":"256","Buyer_QTY":"20"},{"Seller":"Name","Seller_Rate":"256","Saller_QTY":"20","Buyer":"Name","Buyer_Rate":"256","Buyer_QTY":"20"}]}]}]
```

this JSON has Product,Origins,Details such as product has many Origins and origins has different seller,buyer and etc.

my source is- my object class:

```
public class Details
{
    public string Seller { get; set; }
    public string Seller_Rate { get; set; }
    public string Saller_QTY { get; set; }
    public string Buyer { get; set; }
    public string Buyer_Rate { get; set; }
    public string Buyer_QTY { get; set; }
}
public class Origins
{
    public string Origin { get; set; }
    public List<Details> Details { get; set; }
}
public class Products
{
    public List<Origins> Origins { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT { get; set; }
}
```

I have Parsed it inside this method to test result:

```
public async Task<List<Products>> getProductsJson()
    {
        List<Products> root=null;
        Log.Debug("Login", "in get products");
        string responsejson = await client.GetStringAsync(Constants.url_getproducts);
        Log.Debug("Login", responsejson);
        try
        {
            root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Products>>(responsejson);
            Log.Debug("Login",Convert.ToString(root.Count));
            for(int i=0;i<root.Count;i++)
            {
                Log.Debug("Login", "=============================");
                Log.Debug("Login", root[i].PRODUCT);
                for(int j=0;j<root[i].Origins.Count;j++)
                {
                    Log.Debug("Login","   "+root[i].Origins[j].Origin);
                    for(int k=0;k<root[i].Origins[j].Details.Count;k++)
                    {
                        Log.Debug("Login", "       Buy " + root[i].Origins[j].Details[k].Buyer+" BUY_QTY "+ root[i].Origins[j].Details[k].Buyer_QTY);

                    }
                }
                Log.Debug("Login", "=============================");
            }
            //Log.Debug("Login", root[0].PRODUCT);
            //Log.Debug("Login", root[0].Origins[0].Origin);
           // Log.Debug("Login", root[0].Origins[0].Details[0].Seller);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.Debug("Login", e.Message);
            Log.Debug("Login", e.Source);
        }
        return root;
    }
```

As i have printed the log here, this log prints properly up to here every thing is working fine. i have called this method on the xamal page as:

```
async void GetProduct()
    {
        List<Products> result = await App.RestService.getProductsJson();
        list_data.ItemsSource = result;
    }
```

here i have set the result to **listview**.

On Design page:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <RelativeLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout x:Name="logoStack">
            <Label x:Name="lbl_noInternet" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Red" BackgroundColor="Black" />
        </StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="list_data"  HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!--<TextCell Text="{Binding Topic}" TextColor="Purple" Detail="{Binding Description}" DetailColor="Black"/>-->
                    <!--<ImageCell Text="{Binding Topic}" TextColor="Purple" Detail="{Binding Description}" DetailColor="Black" ImageSource="{Binding ImageSource}" />-->
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <StackLayout Spacing="5" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" >
                                <Label Text="{Binding PRODUCT}" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                    <Label   Text="{Binding Origin}" FontSize="20" HorizontalOptions="End" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />
                                </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Now. my code is working fine that means no any error but only PRODUCT is displayed, Origin value is not showing on label.

Now i have 3 questions.

1. as origin is the sub array how to bind it to the label inside listview?
2. which is the best way to achieve this. this same approach or to bind it programmatically?

3.if we need to bind it programmatically means dynamically from .cs file how to do that??

Comment: I would create an OriginDisplay property that returns a string containing the "flattened" data from your array formatted for display

Comment: @Jason can you provide any link or tutorial that shows how to create OriginDisplay and achieve this?

Comment: your product has many origins. what do you want to display in label?

Comment: @YuriS as you see there are many origins and inside that origins there are details. i want to print origins on that label. Actually i wan to put it on the screen same as the JSON Structure, that is Product under that many  Origin and under Origins details of that origin. those are seller,buyer,quantity etc.

Comment: So you want nested listviews then? In your code I see you are putting this into label. If label with just list of origins is enough use what @Jason suggested you, otherwise take a look on grouped listview. If that also is not.enough rethink your design.  Grouping: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface%5CListView%5CGrouping/ 
 Recommendation:  https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/87420/list-view-inside-list-view-with-xaml-viewer#latest

Comment: Jason Smith says "DO NOT nest ListViews. Instead, use groups within a single ListView. Nesting is explicitly unsupported and will break your application."  http://kent-boogaart.com/blog/jason-smith's-xamarin-forms-performance-tips