# Bind subarray in listview xamarin mvvm

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms

Trying to bind a subarray of data in listview.
Lets say I have a json in this format :

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And lets assume this is my model

```
 public class GlossDef
{
    public string para { get; set; }
    public List<string> GlossSeeAlso { get; set; }
}

public class GlossEntry
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string SortAs { get; set; }
    public string GlossTerm { get; set; }
    public string Acronym { get; set; }
    public string Abbrev { get; set; }
    // ===edit=== lets assume I have GlossDef is a list.
    public List<GlossDef> GlossDef { get; set; }
    public string GlossSee { get; set; }
}

public class GlossList
{
    public GlossEntry GlossEntry { get; set; }
}

public class GlossDiv
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public GlossList GlossList { get; set; }
}

public class Glossary
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public GlossDiv GlossDiv { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Glossary glossary { get; set; }
}
```

And lets say this is my xaml :

```
<ListView x:Name="listview" SeparatorVisibility="None" 
              HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Padding="20, 10">
                        <Label  Text="{Binding Title}"/> //this works fine
                        <Label  Text="{Binding Para}"/> //how can I do this
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Is there any way to bind subarray in listview? I tried using nested list views but my app brakes and I read that nested list views usually tend to make my app breake. I was looking into [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/101135/how-to-bind-the-json-sub-array-data-into-listview) which is exactly my problem which he also posted in SO ([How To Bind the JSON Sub Array Data into Listview in xamarin.forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45635815/how-to-bind-the-json-sub-array-data-into-listview-in-xamarin-forms)) but didn't receive the right answer. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you :))

Answer (score 0):

In your ListView you can use only List or ObservableCollection objects. Your List in a `List<string> GlossSeeAlso` so you should bind this object to your ListView and use "{Binding .}" to visualize

GML

XML

...

Comment: Please check my edit. This way how can I bind `para`?! Or is there any other way to do it? @alessandro-caliaro .  
Also the service returns all the json(glossary). So what should the `itemsource` of the listview be?

Comment: you have to bind GlossDef to your ListView and bind "para" property to your control

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a grouped list view.

You would probably have to process your data into a format more suitable for the grouped list view like this.

```
public class EntryList : List<GlossEntry>
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public List<GlossEntry> Entries {get; set;}
}
```

[See here for more details](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-listview-grouping/)